# agSelectCellEditor dropdown shows below mat-dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have an ag-grid in a mat-dialog. The grid has a column that uses agSelectCellEditor. When I click on the column to display the dropdown, it is displayed below the mat-dialog. The column definition is as follows

```
   {
      headerName: 'Subcategory',
      resizable: true,
      field: 'subCategoryName',
      width: 200,
      cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor',
      cellEditorParams: {
        values: ['']
      },
      editable: true,
      cellStyle: function (params) {
        return {
          'background-color': 'white',
          'border-bottom': '1px dotted silver'
        };
      },
```

I have tried changing cellStyle to modify z-index, adding cellClass to use a class with a higher z-index, using ng::deep to find the relevant class and modify the z-index. None of the attempts worked. I wonder if it has to do with cdk-overlay-container but don't know how it works exactly. Could you advise?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tip: This solves the problem.

```
.ag-popup-child { z-index: 9999 !important; }
.ag-popup-editor { z-index: 9999 !important;}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.